# Copy Debug Console to the clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm debugging a Node.js app in Visual Studio Code 1.0.0 and want to copy the entire contents of the Debug Console to the clipboard.  After drag-selecting the Debug Console contents, Edit->Copy only copies the visible parts instead of the entire selection.

Any ideas how to copy the entire selection?  I'd also be okay saving the contents to a file.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to that? It still seems to be a problem in VS Code 1.4.0.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2163

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It only took 13 months (!) but a recent update has added a "Copy All" command to the context menu.

Comment: This also copies the file origin bit, which messes up the output. Tried searching settings to remove it, but couldn't find it either

Comment: I come from 2022 to tell that the debug console is still limited to 10 thousand lines.

Comment: @OdedBenDov In Februari 2021 changes have been made to exclude the file orgin from the `Copy all` button, see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108149 . I can confirm that in VSC version 1.81.1 (August 2023) the `Copy all` button only copies the debug text without the file origin.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is not possible yet. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2163 for details.

Comment: Just a link is not a good answer even if it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to save the response(long one) to a file, which would help me with debugging or copying to clipboard. ***VS Code, debug console output doesn’t prints long output.***

```
const  fs = require('fs');

async function getData(params) {
    try {
        const data = await callApi(params);
        fs.writeFileSync("/Users/response.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); // saves file in local folder (pretty prints the data)
        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        res.status(400).send('Something went wrong while fetching data');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am very late on this but the easy way is to create a log file when you run the node command in the terminal. Something like:

```
PS C:\temp\myprojectfolder>node product.js >product.log
```

This will create the log file and you can easily copy all the content. This also has an added benefit. You won't lose the log even if you accidentally close the terminal window.

Answer (score -3):

You can select from start window and drag the mouse over the textbox at bottom (http://screencast.com/t/Clz24yCo )

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, for me this still only allows me to copy whatever happens to be visible in the console window. I'm looking at some way to copy the entire contents - both visible & hidden.