# Debugging using Visual Studio Code and piping terminal output to a file

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, cmake, vscode-debugger

I am using VS Code to debug an application on Ubuntu, using a launch.json file and cmake to build and debug. This works fine and I can see the output of the program in the terminal as expected. However, I would like to automatically save this output to a file. The way I would do this typically would be something like `mycommand > terminal_output.txt`, however I can't find a way of replicating this using the launch.json file, or alternatively of running the debug through the terminal (e.g. something along the lines of `debug --flags launch.json > terminal_output.txt`).

Here is my launch.json for reference:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++-8 build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++-8 build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way of doing this in a simple way?

Comment: It might help to see your current `launch.json`.  What debugger program are you starting (`gdb`)?  What platform (Windows?).  Do you want the output of the debugged process to go *only* to the file, or to the file as well as the VSCode Terminal window?

Comment: Thanks @ScottMcPeak, I updated the question accordingly (and will provide more information the next time I ask a question). As you noticed in the answers below I managed to hack a solution, but it doesn't seem very robust so maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am using cmake, I was able to achieve this using `cmake.debugConfig` in my `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "cmake.debugConfig": {
        "args": [
            ">",
            "test.txt"
        ]
    }
}
```

Adding `"args"` in `launch.json`, however, did not work.

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer. Googlers, you can tell whether this or "args" is legal for you by using Intellisense (Ctrl+Space). I'm not using cmake, so the best I was able to do was copying the console to the clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153675/copy-debug-console-to-the-clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. install CodeLLDB extension
2. launch.log: inside a CodeLLDB launch configuration add

   "stdio": [null, null, "debug.log"] // stdin/stdout/stderr

[stdio redirection for CodeLLDB](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/blob/master/MANUAL.md#stdio-redirection)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).